# How to use old Google image search instead of new one?

Tags: google-image-search

I frequently use the Google image search. Here in Central Europe they recently deployed a new UI for image search with some fancy pop up windows. Can someone tell me how to switch back to the old style?

Comment: i thought it was worldwide, not only central europe?

Comment: @macha: maybe they are using it worldwide but i am sure only for my area ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Disable new Google Images search style](http://www.techzilo.com/revert-google-images-search-disable-new-style/)

> add the string &sout=1 at the end of the search URL, eg. http://google.com/images?q=sunset&sout=1

OR

> scroll to the end of the search results page and click the link called “Switch to Basic Version”

Hope this helps.

Comment: can i save the setting as "use basic as default"?